# SpringBoot Response Time using RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, resttemplate

Is there anyway to measure response time of a restTemplate in SpringBoot.

I'm calling an API this way, a Sync rest. Is there anyway to measure a Async call too? Or just Sync calls?

```
    public void execute(Request request) {
    this.restTemplate.postForObject(System.getenv("URL"), request, String.class);
}
```

I can use another framework to do the rest call, don't need to be restTemplate, I just want to call an external API using SpringBoot and see how long does take to respond.

Thank you!

Comment: Many ways of doing it, you can use Java `System.currentTime...` method to take a difference of Start and end time of processing, if you are hitting request via `Postman` , the tool also shows a break up of network calls !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there anyway to measure response time of a restTemplate in SpringBoot.

Yes, make a start and a finish timestamp and measure the difference, e.g

```
var start = Instant.now();
this.restTemplate.postForObject(System.getenv("URL"), request, String.class);
long duration = Duration.between(start, Instant.now()).toMillis();
```

However, if you want to keep track of the response time for outgoing requests, I would choose **metrics** as my first place to look at.

If you register a `RestTemplate` like below

```
  @Bean
  public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) {
    return restTemplateBuilder.build();
  }
```

you will get the outgoing request metric `http.client.requests` for free utilizing the Spring Boot actuator, example using Prometheus as monitoring system:

`http_client_requests_seconds_max{clientName="stackoverflow.com",method="GET",outcome="SUCCESS",status="200",uri="/",} 0.398269736`

> Is there anyway to measure a Async call too?

Yes, make a start and a finish timestamp and measure the difference inside the callback from the async invocation. Example using `HttpClient` and
`CompletableFuture`:

```
    var start = Instant.now();
    var completableFuture = HttpClient.newBuilder()
        .build()
        .sendAsync(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString())
        .thenAccept(response -> {
          long duration = Duration.between(start, Instant.now()).toMillis();
          log.info("{} {} took {} ms", request.method(), request.uri(), duration);
        });
    completableFuture.join();
```

Gives
`GET https://stackoverflow.com/ took 395 ms` in the log.